# VB.NET: Persistent line webservice

Tags: vb.net, web-services, httpwebrequest, keep-alive

I currently have absolutely zero experience with webservices in vb.net.

For a project, I have to create an open line between our webservice and an external server, which can receive and send XML-files at any given time.
I have been testing and searching for methods to implement this, but to no avail so far.

Thus my question; is it possible to implement this open line using the HTTPWebRequest class? I have read a lot about the KeepAlive property of said class and it should be able to keep the line open.
So far I have been able to create the HTTPWebRequest, but it does not keep the line open between our webservice and the external server.

I have also tried to use a HTTPListener, but didn't succeed at that either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

What I have right now in code is quite plain:

```
Private _PersistentLine As HttpWebRequest
    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click

    If _PersistentLine Is Nothing Then
        Try
            Dim _Listener As New HttpListener

            _PersistentLine = WebRequest.Create("<External Server Link>")
            _PersistentLine.KeepAlive = True

            _PersistentLine.Method = "GET"
            Dim _Response As HttpWebResponse = CType(_PersistentLine.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            _PersistentLine.Method = "POST"

            MsgBox("ok")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox(_PersistentLine.Headers.ToString)
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

M.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you please showcase the efforts you have made? May be, someone can guide you further. Moreover, formatting your question properly has remarkable effect. You will get answers faster.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) Just edited the post, hope it looks a bit better now.